# Role of the phrase using 'that'

Tags: grammar

> At first, I didn't like her because she was so quiet and so different **that** I thought we were not able to be friends.

In this sentence, I am curious that the role of 'that~' grammatically.

For example, 'that~' is a adverb phrase and it modifies something in the sentence. Please give me the comment like this format.

Comment: **so ... that** =  In such a way or to such an extent that, as in 1. *The line was so long that I could scarcely find the end of it.* In your sentence also it has the same form - *she was **so** adjective **that** I thought we were not able to be friends.* I am not very sure about the role of this **that**, because the **so ... that** seems to be idiomatic. If pushed, I would say that **that** is a subordinator.

Comment: @Man_from_india: Looks like you are right. Intensifier rather than connector, I think.  http://www.grammar-quizzes.com/8-9.html

Answer (score 1):

> At first, I didn't like her because she was so quiet and so different...

The first part is the because, or the explanation of why, in the sentence. it's why he didn't like her at first.

> I thought we were not able to be friends.

This part is like the result or the conclusion of the sentence. so because of the events explained in the first part, this part can be the result

Now: ***that*** takes the first part and points to the second part it's the connector. Because: At first, he didn't like her because she was so quiet and so different **that** -> he thought they were not able to be friends.